# Install package on R 4.2.2 (with Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: r, ubuntu, package, telnet

I am trying to install arrow package on my Ubuntu 20.04 server with `R 4.2.2` by the instruction introduced [here](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/r/articles/install.html) :

```
options(
  HTTPUserAgent =
    sprintf(
      "R/%s R (%s)",
      getRversion(),
      paste(getRversion(), R.version["platform"], R.version["arch"], R.version["os"])
    )
)

install.packages("arrow", repos = "https://packagemanager.rstudio.com/all/__linux__/focal/latest")
```

But I'm getting the eeror :

```
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://packagemanager.rstudio.com/all/__linux__/focal/latest/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://packagemanager.rstudio.com/all/__linux__/focal/latest/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning message:
package ‘arrow’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
```

I'm behind the firewall but can access to `https://packagemanager.rstudio.com/` :

```
telnet packagemanager.rstudio.com 443
Trying 52.1.137.82...
Connected to packagemanager.rstudio.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Any Idea what is wrong here ?

Comment: What does `options("HTTPUserAgent")` return after you run the first part of the code?

Comment: @MrFlick `options("HTTPUserAgent")
$HTTPUserAgent

[1] "R/4.2.2 R (4.2.2 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu x86_64 linux-gnu)"
`